# Javascript/PHP to update innerHTML of multiple items

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to to use Javascript to update the innerHTML of a webpage after an onclick event. My Javascript (java.js) uses [this code](http://www.crackajax.net/ahahLib.js) to access a PHP page which echoes back the text that goes in the innerHTML. The thing is, I want to update the innerHTML of two items (a "color" table and an "item" table) which are not located next to each other and have different element ID's. Each call from java.js works fine individually (like if one is commented out), but when both of them are run, whichever one is first will get stuck on the "loading" message and the second one will work. Loading "content.php?item='5'&color='5'" in a web browser shows both tables.

I suspect this is something to do with the mechanics of $_GET[] (which I don't totally understand; this is my first time working with PHP). But the calls should happen sequentially and the keys ('item' and 'color') don't conflict, so I can't figure out what's going wrong.

### java.js:

```
function makeActive(active_tab) {
    //item table
    callAHAH('content.php?item='+active_tab, 'item', 'getting items for tab '+active_tab+'. Wait...', 'Error');

    //color table
    callAHAH('content.php?color='+active_tab, 'color', 'getting colors for tab '+active_tab+'. Wait...', 'Error');
}
```

### content.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['color'])) {
    require 'color.php';

    $index = 1*$_GET['color'];
    $arr = $ITEM_TYPES[$index];
    echoColorTable($arr); //makes table in color.php
} else {
    echo "color not set "; //debug
}

if (isset($_GET['item'])) {
    require 'item.php';

    $index = 1*$_GET['item'];
    echoItemTable($index); //makes table in item.php
} else {
    echo "item not set "; //debug
}
```

Comment: Java isn't JavaScript. The only resemblance they share is just a part of their name.

Comment: @Blender. he just called the file java.js, not a big deal.

Comment: @Blender, gdoron: Yes, I just called the file java.js--it isn't meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the [callAHAH](http://www.crackajax.net/ahahLib.js) function you linked to. It doesn't have a `var` keyword when it declares `req`. So it is a global variable and there can only ever be one request at once. It also reuses that global variable in the responseAHAH function. In general global variables are a bad idea for reasons like this. I recommend ditching the callAHAH function altogether and using something like this which does the exact same thing without using a global variable:

```
function loadInto(url, id, loading, error) {
    var ajax;
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.innerHTML = loading;

    if (typeof XMLHttpRequest !== 'undefined')
        ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else // Some people still support IE 6
        ajax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajax.readyState === 4){
            if(ajax.status == 200){
                el.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }else{
                el.innerHTML = error;
            }
        }
    };

    ajax.open('GET', url);
    ajax.send();
}
```

It's also not named `callAHAH`, and that's always a plus.